# OCaml syntax trap: multiple lets using separators

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to teach myself OCaml. I've been going nuts over this one syntax trap. I'm told that you can string expressions together in sequence using ";" ie, expr1 ; expr2 executes the first expr, then the second, as expected. For some reason, I cannot get the interpreter to agree with the following input

```
let x = 5 ; let y = 7;;
```

Bizarrely if ONLY the first expr is a let, it works. So

```
let x = 5 ; 7;;
```

Passes, and evaluates to 7.
Even worse, if I attempt to use parens to compose multiple sequences of statements where the let comes first, it still does not work. I.E.:

```
let x = 5 ; (let y = 7 ; 9);;
```

Is an error, even though it consists only of sequences where lets are the first expression. Can someone explain how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to look at the problem is that `let x = 5` isn't an expression. It's a top-level declaration; i.e., it declares a name `x` with a value 5.

The `;` operator works for combining expressions, but not for declarations.

You don't need to string declarations together with `;`. You can just put one after the other:

```
# let x = 5 let y = 7;;
val x : int = 5
val y : int = 7
#
```

There is a *completely different* use of `let` in OCaml that is part of an expression. In that case it's followed by `in`:

```
# (let x = 4 in x + 1);;
- : int = 5
```

Since this is an expression, you can string several of them together with `;`:

```
# (let x = 4 in x + 1); (let y = 6 in y + 1);;
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
- : int = 7
```

However, as the compiler is warning you, it's not idiomatic to string together arbitrary expressions. Normally you use `;` with imperative code. With functional code it doesn't make sense. So the compiler expects all but the last expression to have type `unit` (which is used for imperative code that does something useful but doesn't return a useful value).